# Relative Layout Overlapping

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am creating my own Custom Actionbar with a Relative Layout. I added a Progressbar a Button and a SrcollView with a Layout. With Java i add a text into this Layout but the text is displayed only for half horizontally. Why?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zsvrg3cia379km/Screenshot_2013-05-31-16-54-02.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionsearch"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/directory_buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/actionsearch"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/search" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionsearch"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Quite frankly, you should be using the ActionBar provided by the framework. What is it the system ActionBar cannot do that made you decide to create your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your progress bar

```
   android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_text"
```

Comment: then i get an error because i already wrote android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionsearch" in Srcollview and when i remove it and add yours to progressbar, the progress bar is not shown

Comment: remove this from scroll view android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"

Comment: i solved my problem with deleting android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_text" and android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar" ! Thanks for help